# SSIS Transfer Objects task fails when run from Agent

Tags: t-sql, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, agent

I am using the SSIS Transfer Objects task to transfer a database from one server to another. This is a nightly task as the final part of ETL.

If I run the task manually during the day, there is no problem. It completes in around 60 to 90 minutes.

When I run the task from Agent, it always starts but often fails . I have the agent steps set up to rety on failure, but most nights it is taking 3 attempts. On some nights 5 or 6 attempts.

The error message returned is two fold (both error messages show in the log for the same row):-

1) An error occurred while transferring data. See the inner exception for details.

2) Timeout expired: The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

I can't find any timeout limit to adjust that I haven't already adjusted.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If you are transferring millions of rows data, your memory and I/O will give up resulting in timeouts, Unless u have a best Flash drive in source and destination. I suggest you to consider a Better approach like `merge replication`, `log shipping` etc...

Comment: if it were a memory or I/O issue then why would it run perfectly from SSIS every time?

Comment: As u said, when u run it manually it takes around 60-90 minutes, thats lot of time for Agent job to maintain connection without timing out, which edition of SQL you are using , Query `select @@version` from query window. Try scheduling the same job in `Windows scheduler` and check.

Comment: Are there other jobs doing heavy lifting during the same hours at night?   Maybe you need to find another window for this job to run in so it doesn't compete with other jobs.

Comment: There shouldn't be any other heavy jobs.Agent just passes control to SSIS. I am copying data from SQL Server 2012 BI to SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise.

Comment: Copy is limited to tables and keys

Comment: It appears that the task just isn't very good. I have reverted to doing the transfer via SQL and it works perfectly and efficiently.